how to derive $(((A \leftrightarrow \neg B) \leftrightarrow \neg A) \leftrightarrow B)$ with no premises?
So I started with the bi-implication introduction, which left me with the new subgoal of proving B, and here is where I get stuck.


So I started with the bi-implication introduction, which left me with the new subgoal of proving B, and here is where I get stuck.

Tip, if you cannot show that $((A\leftrightarrow\neg B)\leftrightarrow\neg A)$ entails $B$ directly, then you should try to show that the assumptions of $((A\leftrightarrow\neg B)\leftrightarrow\neg A)$ and $\neg B$ reduce to absurdity.
Hint: $A\vee\neg A$ is a tautology in Classical Logic, so if you can show that both entail a contradiction under the assumptions, then your job is done (for that subgoal).

$\def\fitch#1#2{~~\begin{array}{|l}#1\\\hline#2\end{array}}
\fitch{}{\fitch{((A \leftrightarrow \neg B) \leftrightarrow \neg A)}{\fitch{\neg B}{\fitch{A}{~\vdots\\\bot}\\\neg A\\~\vdots\\\bot}\\\neg\neg B\\B}\\\fitch{B}{~\vdots\\(A\leftrightarrow\neg B)\leftrightarrow\neg A}\\(((A \leftrightarrow \neg B) \leftrightarrow \neg A) \leftrightarrow B)}$

Thank you so much, I'm much more used to gentzen-style tree, so it was a bit difficult to understand what you did there but I got it, thanks for your help, just finished the whole derivation.
